# Edit Find File Types in Visual Studio Search

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Is there a way to edit the File Types that Visual Studio uses when performing a search?

Currently, it does not include any `*.json` files, and I imagine there would be other file types I would like to search.

There is not an option to search all (i.e. `*.*`).

[image: screenshot]